# Is there a free/cheap tool that prints out the size of each macroblock on a H.264 stream?

Tags: h.264, video-processing

I am working on analyzing the size of different regions of a frame using different encoding settings. Having a tool like that would simplify my work a lot.
An open source tool that could be modified to reach this point would also be helpful.
Of course ffmpeg can be modified to get this, but I was hoping there would be something simpler made for analysis and not for playback.

Comment: maybe belongs on software-recs.SE, since unfortunately it doesn't meet the criteria for SO or video.SE (no software-recommendation questions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this free tool:

**[H.264/AVC Coding Inspector Tool](http://vidosearch.com/?p=506)** or save the [zip directly](http://vidosearch.com/demos/AVCReader.zip)

I dont know what language you are coding in but if you need some source code to import then you could contact that author about it.